# In C# How can we determine if a caller is using Windows PowerShell 5.1 or a newer version?

Tags: c#, powershell

From PowerShell we can easily check if a caller is using Windows PowerShell 5.1 or a newer version using the [`$PSVersionTable` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#psversiontable):

```bash
$PSVersion = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
if ($PSVersion.Major -eq 5 -and $PSVersion.Minor -eq 1) {
    # do 5.1 stuff here
    return
}

# do 6+ stuff here
```

Or we could even use [`$IsCoreCLR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#iscoreclr):

```bash
if ($IsCoreCLR) {
    # do 6+ stuff here
    return
}

# do 5.1 stuff here
```

How could we do the same from C# if targeting [`netstandard2.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way we can determine this is by checking the value of the [`PSVersionInfo.PSVersion` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psversioninfo.psversion?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-psversioninfo-psversion), this method requires reflection as the `PSVersionInfo` class was not exposed in Windows PowerShell 5.1.

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Testing;

internal static class PSVersion
{
    private static bool? s_isCore;

    // internal assuming we don't want to expose this
    internal static bool IsCoreCLR => s_isCore ??= IsCore();

    private static bool IsCore()
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(PowerShell)
            .Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.PSVersionInfo")
            .GetProperty(
                "PSVersion",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);

        return (Version)property.GetValue(property) is not { Major: 5, Minor: 1 };
    }
}
```

Another way to do it if we're leveraging [`PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) is by getting the value of `IsCoreCLR` through the cmdlet's [`SessionState` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.sessionstate?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-pscmdlet-sessionstate):

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Testing;

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "PSVersion")]
public sealed class TestPSVersionCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    private static bool? s_isCore;

    private bool IsCoreCLR => s_isCore ??= IsCore();

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        if (IsCoreCLR)
        {
            // call 6+ method here
            return;
        }

        // call 5.1 method here
    }

    private bool IsCore() =>
        (bool?)SessionState.PSVariable.GetValue("IsCoreCLR") is true;
}
```